# Libcurl+QtCreator+debian

Tags: c++, qt, curl, libcurl, qmake

I am a newbie on Linux, so I have a lot of trouble with it.

I want to use curl in my Qt Project (C++). I created the project, then write in my main.cpp

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main( void ){
    CURL *curl;

    /* First step, init curl */
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl) {
       return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried compile that code, but have one error: undefined reference to 'curl_easy_init()'
Than i realise, that QT Creator wants know path to library.
I open test.pro file and append:

```
INCLUDEPATH += /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

LIBS += /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl.a
LIBS += /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurldll.a
```

And then error: libcurlldll.a no such file or dirrectory.
Definetly a haven't this library, but i try install/reinstall all types of libcurl and it doesn't work.

Sites, where i tried to search information:

> http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/89488/
>
> http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/using/apps.html
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/

Please, redirect me to very simple guide "How use libcurl in QT Creator on Debian" or something like that. I need step-by-step guide. Or can you write it to me there, then everyone can use it?

Sorry for my english, i am just learning. Thanks!

Comment: do you have libcurl-dev installed? have you tried `LIBS+=-lcurl` only?

Comment: Yes and yes. And i have read almost all posts about libcurl on stackoverflow

Comment: I added the libcurl.dll.a file project and used a library importer to create the library dependency. But it still gives undefined errors. What declaration have I gone wrong at? Did you get your errors fixed with this? Can you also share the code? I am trying to instantiate curl from widget constructor.= unlike in the main. Error is >>> :-1: error: undefined reference to _imp__curl_easy_init' and error are there for other curl functions as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This works for me just fine:

#### main.cpp

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main( void ){
    CURL *curl;

    /* First step, init curl */
    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl) {
       return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

### main.pro

```
TEMPLATE = app
TARGET = curl
QT -= core gui

LIBS += -lcurl

# CONFIG += link_pkgconfig
# PKGCONFIG += curl

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

As you can see in the comment, you could also use pkgconfig instead of the `LIBS` variable which would probably be even neater.

Make sure you have all the corresponding packages installed that are necessary, for instance the development, etc.

Comment: Thanks! It is completely full answer. But I would like to clarify: is "link_pkgconfig" mean path to pkgconfig (because it's doesn't work in this case) or it is something else?

Comment: @gek0n: it means that Qt will use pkgconfig support for the "foo" attached to the PKGCONFIG variable. The curl package config file (.pc) is broken on my Archlinux, so you may suffer from the same issue, but it is hopefully not a Qt side issue.

Comment: I added the libcurl.dll.a file project and used a library importer to create the library dependency. But it still gives undefined errors. What declaration have I gone wrong at? Did you get your errors fixed with this? Can you also share the code? I am trying to instantiate curl from widget constructor.= unlike in the main. Error is >>> :-1: error: undefined reference to _imp__curl_easy_init' and error are there for other curl functions as well.